# Undo a disk format while disk is still attached

Tags: linux, mount, disk, fdisk, mkfs

I've been struggling with a disk that's a logical volume. Disk would not work with me and I decided to partion and format the disk.. Then realized that I have de-attached and attached the disk without rebooting. Upon rebooting the machine, I was able to work with the disk again.

After reboot I've found that I lost data on the disk since I did a partition and format. Looking through the history, I've executed all kind of commands in the time of frustration:

```
fdisk
mount
umount
wipefs
mkfs.ext4
```

Luckily I had a backup from the point just before I rebooted the vm so I reverted back. BUT no backup before I did a partition and format. So the state of machine is: Data/files still there until machine reboots. Is there a way to undo disk format that I did here? To save the data/files that has been wiped/formatted but still there since disk is still attached and machine not rebooted?

Comment: If you really still can access the data attach a different device and create a backup first.

Comment: @eblock cannot attach a device anymore. Long story. I'm running docker container on this troubled machine that also uses a database container. 

Nonetheless, I have another machine unused so I'm planning to rsync datas to that temporarily during the fix. Unsure if data will still be intact once I've rsynced back and forth from the troubled machine and the backup machine.